# Python ThreadPoolExecutor is faster than a loop for CPU-bound task. How come?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Recently I've been working on a project, and found behaviour that I don't understand. We have endpoint that fetches documents from mongodb and then applies transformation to each document, replacing some symbols in data using regex. And what's bothering me is that for 7400 documents applying transformation function in a regular loop takes 6 seconds to finish. And using `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` finishes in 3.4 seconds. As far as I know `GIL` prevents python interpreter from running more that one thread simultaneously, so for CPU-bound tasks should run slower in `ThreadPoolExecutor` than in regular loop. But this is not a case here. How so? I'm assuming that `re` operations somehow release `GIL` but not sure. Here is code:

```
# parts that are responsible for substituting symbols in mongo document

class Converter:

    def __init__(self, reverse=False):
        self.reverse = reverse

    def key_convert(self, key, reverse, path):
        return key

    def value_convert(self, value, reverse, path):
        return value

    def recurse(self, data, path=tuple()):
        if isinstance(data, Mapping):
            _data = {}
            for k, v in data.items():
                next_path = path + (k,)
                key = self.key_convert(k, self.reverse, path)
                value = self.value_convert(v, self.reverse, next_path)
                _data[key] = self.recurse(value, next_path)
            return _data

        elif isinstance(data, Iterable) and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)):
            return [
                self.recurse(it, path + (idx,))
                for idx, it in enumerate(data)]

        return self.value_convert(data, self.reverse, path)

    def convert(self, data):
        self.reverse = False
        return self.recurse(data)

    def unconvert(self, data):
        self.reverse = True
        return self.recurse(data)


class MongoConverter(Converter):
    _to_mongo = ((rec(r"\."), "\u00B7"), (rec(r"^\$"), "#"),)
    _from_mongo = ((rec("\u00B7"), "."), (rec("^#"), "$"),)

    def key_convert_to_mongo(self, key):
        return pattern_substitute(key, self._to_mongo)

    def key_convert_from_mongo(self, key):
        return pattern_substitute(key, self._from_mongo)

    def key_convert(self, key, reverse, _):
        if reverse:
            return self.key_convert_from_mongo(key)
        return self.key_convert_to_mongo(key)

    def value_convert(self, value, reverse, path):
        if reverse:
            return value
        return as_datetime(value)


def pattern_substitute(value, pattern_substitutes):
    for pattern, substitute in pattern_substitutes:
        value = pattern.sub(substitute, value)
    return value

# storage adapter

class MongoStorage:
  
    def __init__(self, collection, converter=None):
        self.collection = collection
        self.converter = converter if converter else MongoConverter()
        self._context = None
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

    def after_find(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            return self.converter.unconvert(data)

    def find(self, filtr=None, limit=-1, **kwargs):
        filtr = filter_converter.convert(filtr)
        if limit == 0:
            return []
        if limit == -1:
            limit = 0
        # this part is what I'm asking about. Regular loop here is slower
        return self.executor.map(
            self.after_find,
            self.collection.find(filtr, limit=limit, **kwargs)
        )
```

Thank you for answers.